# jquery Cookie and CSS

Tags: jquery, css, cookies

I have a script that will change font sizes for particular divs. I have added cookie functions to store the values so that the next page will display the text at the new size. I know that the cookies are carrying the value, but how do I make the new page change the font size to the new value?

Here's my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var fSize = $.cookie('fSize');
        if (fSize) {
            $('html').css('font-size', fSize);
            var originalFontSize = fSize;
        } else {

        }

        $(".resetFont").click(function(){
            $('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
          $.cookie('fSize', originalFontSize, { path : '/' });

        });

        // Increase Font Size
        $(".increaseFont").click(function(){
            var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
            var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
            var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.1;
            $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
            $.cookie('fSize', newFontSize, { path : '/' });
            return false;
        });

        // Decrease Font Size
        $(".decreaseFont").click(function(){
            var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
            var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
            var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum/1.1;
            $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
            $.cookie('fSize', newFontSize, { path : '/' });
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Did you try to insert your script in each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using parseFloat() in your function. That removes the px (or whatever you use to define your font size) and you never add it back.

Try something like

```
$('html').css('font-size', fSize + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing 'html' with 'body', like so:

```
var fSize = $.cookie('fSize');
if (fSize) {
    $('body').css('font-size', fSize);
    var originalFontSize = fSize;
}
```

Maybe you need to add `+ 'em'` to `fSize` or % or something. Otherwise, I didn't see any immediate flags with your script.. It looked fine to me.

---

**Edit**

On an unrelated note, you could combine two of those functions into one since they are almost identical.

```
// Increase Font Size
$('.increaseFont, .decreaseFont').click(function() {
    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = (this.className.match('increaseFont'))
        ? currentFontSizeNum * 1.1
        : currentFontSizeNum / 1.1;
    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    $.cookie('fSize', newFontSize, { path : '/' });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both. Adding "+ 'em'" worked partially. I had to make some adjustments to account for the 1em being the same as 16px (font-size), because I set my body font size by percentage. Once I'd changed  that, I could upscale the font and recall it perfectly. Thanks for your help.  Here's the final code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var originalFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');

            var fSize = $.cookie('fSize');
            if (fSize) {
                $('html').css('font-size', fSize + 'em');
            } else {
                var originalFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
            }

            $(".resetFont").click(function(){
                $('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
                $.cookie('fSize', originalFontSize, { path : '/' });

            });

                 // Increase Font Size
            $(".increaseFont").click(function(){
                    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
                    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
              var newFontSizelg = Math.round(currentFontSizeNum*1.1) / 16;
                $('html').css('font-size', newFontSizelg + 'em');
                $.cookie('fSize', newFontSizelg, { path : '/' });
                return false;
            });

            // Decrease Font Size
            $(".decreaseFont").click(function(){
                var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
                var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
              var newFontSizesm = Math.round(currentFontSizeNum/1.1) / 16 ;
                $('html').css('font-size', newFontSizesm + 'em');
                $.cookie('fSize', newFontSizesm, { path : '/' });
                return false;
            });
        });
}
```